# How to construct a class with user inputs and no variables?

Tags: c++, class

One of my assignments involve creating a class using a constructor with parameters, where the arguments sent to create the object are based on user input.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "HRCalc_lib.h"

HeartRates::HeartRates(const std::string &first, const std::string &last, 
        int day, int month, int year){
    firstName = first;
    lastName = last;
    setBirthYear(year);
    setBirthMonth(month);
    setBirthDay(day);
}
```

**Note:** This is from a `.cpp` file where member functions are fully written. All other class syntax is in a header file.

I approached creating an object with this constructor using `std::cin` with variables through `main`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "HRCalc_lib.h"

int main(){
    std::string first, last;
    int Bday, Bmonth, Byear;
    std::cout << "enter your name (first last) & date of birth (dd mm yyyy) seperated by spaces" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> first >> last >> Bday >> Bmonth >> Byear;

    HeartRates person1(first, last, Bday, Bmonth, Byear);

//further code would be implemented here
    return 0;
}
```

Is there a more direct way of creating the same object without the need for variables in main?

Comment: Um, where else are you going to store that input?

Comment: @NicolBolas Perhaps I should clarify a bit, I'm not seeking any further use for these variables so storing them would be pointless. I'm simply looking to create a class with user input as means to send arguments to my constructor function

Comment: You could move them into place but other than that there isn’t much more you can do here

Comment: @Goroz You can use **operator overloading** as shown in my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a more direct way of creating the same object without the need for variables to store user inputs in main?

Yes, there is. You can use **operator overloading**. In particular, you can overload `operator>>` as shown below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>

class HeartRates
{
   private:
      std::string first, last;
      int day = 0, month = 0, year = 0;
   //friend declaration for overloaded operator>>
   friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, HeartRates& obj);
};
//implement overloaded operator<<
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, HeartRates& obj)
{
    is >> obj.first >> obj.last >> obj.day >> obj.month >> obj.year;
    
    if(is)//check that input succeded
    {
        //do something here 
    }
    else //input failed: give the object a default state
    {
        
        obj = HeartRates();
    }
    return is;
}
int main(){
    
    HeartRates person1;
    //NO NEED TO CREATE SEPARATE VARIABLES HERE AS YOU WANT
    
    std::cout << "enter your name (first last) & date of birth (dd mm yyyy) seperated by spaces" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> person1; //this uses overloaded operator>>

    return 0;
}
```

The output of the above program can be seen [here](https://onlinegdb.com/lDd44lRYk).

Here when we wrote:

```
std::cin >> person1;
```

we're using the overloaded `operator>>` and so you don't need to create separate variables inside `main`.

Comment: Are the if statements there in case of invalid user input (Exception code basically) or is there a more blatant reason? Is there some obvious error input to consider when implementing overloads? I'm asking because I have user input checks already in my program.

Comment: @Goroz Yes the `if`/`else` inside the overloaded `operator>>` is there to deal with invalid input. It is good practice to leave the object in a default state in case the user enters invalid data.